# Using selenium web driver to run test on multiple browsers

Tags: browser, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to run a same test across multiple browsers through for loop but it always run only on Firefox.

```
bros = ['FIREFOX','CHROME','INTERNET EXPLORER']

for bro in bros:
    print "Running "+bro+"\n"
    browser = webdriver.Remote(
                    command_executor='http://10.236.194.218:4444/wd/hub',
                    desired_capabilities={'browserName': bro,
                                          'javascriptEnabled': True})
    browser.implicitly_wait(60000)
    browser.get("http://10.236.194.156")
```

One interesting observation; when I include the parameter `platform: WINDOWS` it's running only on Internet Explorer.

Does Selenium Webdriver works this way or my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually have done this in java, the following works well for me:

```
...
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
...

DesiredCapabilities[] browsers = {DesiredCapabilities.firefox(),DesiredCapabilities.chrome(),DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer()};
    for(DesiredCapabilities browser : browsers)
    {
        try{
            System.out.println("Testing in Browser: "+browser.getBrowserName());
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), browser);
            ...
```

You will need to adapt this of course if you're writing your tests in a different language, I know it's possible in Java, not sure about otherwise.

Also, I agree with what you're trying to do, I think it is much better to have a class that runs the same tests with different browsers, instead of duplicating code many times over and being inelegant. If you are doing this in Java/other codes, I also highly suggest using a [Page Object](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try in similar way and update you on the progress. :-)

Comment: hey have you tried running multiple instance of same browser? I am trying with chrome but it is failing, but my constructor starts with new ChromeDriver(). do you think is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So if I got you right, you have one testcase and want this to be tested against different browsers.

I don't think a loop is a good idea even if it's possible (I don't know atm).

The idea is to be able to test every testcase standalone on the run with a specific browser (thats the JUnit philosophy), not to run all in order to get to that specific browser .

So you need to create a WebDriver with the specific browser and the specific testcase.

I suggest you seperate testcases by creating a testcase-class file for each browser.

Like: FirefoxTestOne.java, IeTestOne.java, ChromeTestOne.java .

Note that you can add multiple firefox tests in the FirefoxTestOne without problems. Theres no guarantee that they will be executed in a particular order through (JUnit philosophy).

For links and tutorials ask google. There are already looooots of examples written.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to generate multiple test classes (or webdriver instances) with the chosen browsers.
A Webdriver is defined with one browser.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do inside the for loop. After the `browser.get()` I have `browser.close()` function. Hence when the for loop starts next iteration it should create a new driver object with driver specific to the new bro variable.

Answer (score 0):

As Coretek said you need multiple webdriver instances. You will need to run the selenium-server .jar file and provide each one with an argument specifying the browser you want that instance of the server to run.

The argument for Internet Explorer is *iexplore, the argument for firefox is *firefox and the argument for chrome is *chrome. These are -forcedBrowserMode arguments. Otherwise selenium won't know what it should be running against. You may need to use *iexploreProxy for your tests, sometimes it works better than the *iexplore mode.

Check out this link for more arguments that may be useful:

http://seleniumforum.forumotion.net/t89-selenium-server-command-options-while-starting-server

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's not been mentioned anywhere in the documentation that for each new browser type we need to have separate server instance & I have used single selenium server instance and used it to access IE, FF, Chrome & Safari using Selenium RC. And also the argument model of *iexplore/*firefox is for Selenium RC, isn't it? I'm trying to create test case using Selenium 2.0 (Webdriver). Please point me if there is any document which helps me on it.

Comment: It still works with Webdriver as of 2.6 (I haven't updated in a while)

Comment: If you run selinium as a host and a node you can provide a config file for all the browsers you want (or can fit on the same machine)

Answer (score 0):

This way (attached url) worked for me.

http://blog.varunin.com/2011/07/running-selenium-tests-on-different.html

The following point is different from the example.

```
@Parameters
public static List data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{{"firefox"},{"ie"}});
}
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("browser: " + browser);
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer64.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    } else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestNG for this 
combination of selenium + testng gives you a batter result for this 
just by adding parameters attribute you can do this

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [composite design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to create a CompositeWebDriver that actually runs multiple component WebDriver (such as chrome, gecko,...)? To this end, you would extend the WebDriver class with a new one (e.g. CompositeWebDriver) that just delegates his calls to all the actual WebDrivers.

This could also be done with various instances of RemoteWebDriver as components.